# Objective C Calculator Programming Variable

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

Okay, so I've been working on the Stanford iOS development course that they have posted for free online. I've been working on figuring out how to make a programable variable. It has been working fine so far, aside from the fact that I think the following lines of code are programming the variable to be @"x=" instead of the previous number entered.

The View Controller:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "CalculatorBrain.h"

@interface ViewController()
@property (nonatomic) BOOL userIsInTheMiddleOfEnteringANumber;
@property (nonatomic) BOOL userPressedSomethingElse;
@property (nonatomic, strong) CalculatorBrain *brain;
@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize display;
@synthesize inputHistory;
@synthesize userPressedSomethingElse;
@synthesize userIsInTheMiddleOfEnteringANumber;
@synthesize brain = _brain;

- (CalculatorBrain *)brain
{
    if (!_brain) _brain = [[CalculatorBrain alloc] init];
    return _brain;
}

NSString *xValue = @"0";

- (IBAction)enterPressed 
// A specific action if enter is pressed
{
    [self.brain pushOperand:[self.display.text doubleValue]];
    self.userIsInTheMiddleOfEnteringANumber = NO;
    if (self.userPressedSomethingElse) 
    {
        self.inputHistory.text = [self.inputHistory.text stringByAppendingString:@" "];
    }
    self.userPressedSomethingElse = NO;
}

- (IBAction)variableChanged:(id)sender 
{
    if (self.userIsInTheMiddleOfEnteringANumber) 
    {
        [self enterPressed];
    }
    NSString *operation = [sender currentTitle];
    xValue = [self.brain programVariable:operation];
    self.inputHistory.text = [self.inputHistory.text stringByAppendingString:@"X="];
    self.inputHistory.text = [self.inputHistory.text stringByAppendingString:xValue];
}
```

The Calculator Brain (the .m one):

```
#import "CalculatorBrain.h"

@interface CalculatorBrain()
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSMutableArray *operandStack;
@end

@implementation CalculatorBrain

@synthesize operandStack = _operandStack;
- (NSMutableArray *) operandStack
{
    if (!_operandStack) 
    {
        _operandStack = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    return _operandStack;
}

- (void) pushOperand:(double)operand
{
    NSNumber *operandObject = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:operand];
    [self.operandStack addObject:operandObject];
}

- (double)popOperand
{
    NSNumber *operandObject = [self.operandStack lastObject];
    if (operandObject) [self.operandStack removeLastObject];
    return [operandObject doubleValue];
}

- (NSString *) programVariable: (NSString *) operation
{
    double result = [self popOperand];
    NSString *resultString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2d",result];
    return resultString;
}
```

The .h Calculator Brain:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface CalculatorBrain : NSObject

- (void) pushOperand: (double) operand;
- (double) performOperation: (NSString *) operation;
- (NSString *) programVariable: (NSString *) operation;

@end
```

The button that is pushed says "x=", and because of some tracing statements I added, I have figured out that this is being set to xValue. However, I don't know how to fix it... Any ideas?

Comment: You wrote `@synthesize brain = _brain;` why do you still write self.brain? What do your log-lines show?

Comment: I mean your tracing statements. What do they show?

Answer (score 0):

In your `variableChanged:`method, you possibly want `if (!self.userIsInTheMiddleOfEnteringANumber)` at the beginning. Note the logical negation, which I derive the need from the sense of your variable name. I see no way that variable is set, so I trust you are properly setting it elsewhere in your app.

Also, change the variable `xValue` to a instance variable on `ViewController`. It is currently a global static variable. If you have more than one `ViewController` objects created, you will have problems.

Comment: No, because the way I do it cuts off whatever number they are entering, so that it does not process it as 3.5x=8, only x= 3.5.